# Slider user control with float values

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

The float word I think is inappropriate but...
I try to make a custom slider control and seems to work fine but for some reason for some values the control crashes.
For example if I choose Maximum value = 1.112 the slider show maximum 1.111 and if I increase the value with numeric Up Down I get this error:

> System Argument Out Of Range Exception H Result = 0x80131502
> Message=Value of '1112' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be
> between 'Minimum' and 'Maximum'.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UserSliderControl
{
    //set the default event for this user control
    [DefaultEvent("ValueChanged")]

    public partial class SliderControl : UserControl
    {
        //set the initial values
        private int multiplier = 1;
        private float minimum = 0f;
        private float maximum = 100f;
        private int decimalPlaces = 0;
        private float _value = 0f;
        private float resetvalue = 0f;
        private int largeChange = 5;
        private Image buttonResetImage = null;
        private Color controlNameForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;

        //set the event handler for this user control = ValueChanged
        public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

        //set the properties for this user control
        #region properties
        public string ControlName
        {
            get { return labelControlName.Text; }
            set
            {
                labelControlName.Text = value;
            }
        }
        public Color ControlNameForeColor
        {
            get { return controlNameForeColor; }
            set
            {
                controlNameForeColor = value;
                labelControlName.ForeColor = controlNameForeColor;
            }
        }

        public Image ButtonResetImage
        {
            get { return buttonResetImage; }
            set
            {
                buttonResetImage = value;
                btnReset.BackgroundImage = buttonResetImage;
                btnReset.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
            }
        }

        public float Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                if (_value > maximum) _value = maximum;
                if (_value < minimum) _value = minimum;
                NumericUpDown.Value = (decimal)_value;
            }
        }

        public float ResetValue
        {
            get { return resetvalue; }
            set
            {
                resetvalue = value;
                if (resetvalue > maximum) resetvalue = maximum / 2;
                if (resetvalue < minimum) resetvalue = minimum;
            }
        }

        public float Maximum
        {
            get { return maximum; }
            set
            {
                maximum = value;
                if (maximum < minimum)
                {
                    maximum = 2 * minimum;
                }
                TrackBar.Maximum = (int)(maximum * multiplier);
                NumericUpDown.Maximum = (decimal)maximum;
            }
        }

        public float Minimum
        {
            get { return minimum; }
            set
            {
                minimum = value;
                if (minimum > maximum)
                {
                    minimum = 0;
                }
                TrackBar.Minimum = (int)minimum * multiplier;
                NumericUpDown.Minimum = (int)minimum;
            }
        }

        public int DecimalPlaces
        {
            get { return decimalPlaces; }
            set
            {
                decimalPlaces = value;
                if (decimalPlaces > 3)
                {
                    decimalPlaces = 3;
                }
                multiplier = (int)Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
                NumericUpDown.DecimalPlaces = decimalPlaces;
                NumericUpDown.Increment = 1m / multiplier;
            }
        }

        public int LargeChange
        {
            get { return largeChange; }
            set
            {
                largeChange = value;
                TrackBar.LargeChange = largeChange;

            }
        }
        #endregion

        public SliderControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TrackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NumericUpDown.Value = (decimal)TrackBar.Value / multiplier;
            Value = (float)TrackBar.Value / multiplier;
            OnValueChanged();
        }

        private void NumericUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TrackBar.Value = (int)(NumericUpDown.Value * multiplier);
            Value = (float)NumericUpDown.Value;
            OnValueChanged();
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NumericUpDown.Value = (decimal)ResetValue;
            TrackBar.Focus();
            OnValueChanged();   
        }

        protected virtual void OnValueChanged()
        {
            ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `decimal`, not `float`

Comment: Thanks man. Using decimal instead float solve my problems.